# No command output when running: 'am start -n

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt

Lately, when I'm trying to run my Android apps on my device, I have to run it several times from Eclipse before it actually starts.

I have tried to reinstall JRE, JDK and the IDE and I have tried to switch workspaces. I have also let Eclipse use more RAM for the Java VM.

Both my IDE, JRE, JDK, ADTand ADT-plugin are up to date.

Any suggestions on this are very much appreciated.

> No command output when running: 'am start -n com.example.abstab/com.example.abstab.ActivityMain -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device HT15CV805781

Exception Stack Trace:

```
com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:408)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:453)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(ActivityLaunchAction.java:67)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(ActivityLaunchAction.java:109)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doLaunchAction(AndroidLaunchController.java:1277)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doLaunchAction(AndroidLaunchController.java:1289)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launchApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:1261)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.simpleLaunch(AndroidLaunchController.java:906)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.continueLaunch(AndroidLaunchController.java:748)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launch(AndroidLaunchController.java:640)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.doLaunch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:322)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_15
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/myname/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/myname/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

Comment: Did you found your problem solved? I am having same problem here.

Comment: I haven't found a solution. I have recently installed a different ROM on my device, so maybe restoring factory defaults may help your problem? I still don't know if it was the machine I developed on or the device causing the problem. :(

Comment: So you want to say that I reinstall adt bundle for android?

Comment: @FastTrack I haven't been able to reproduce the problem on my current system after restoring factory defaults on my device.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same most of the time, and it works when I restart [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) server. Most of the time, ADB goes into a sort of limbo (specially when emulators are starting afresh), and I've had to restart it manually like:

```
adb kill-server
adb start
```

After restarting ADB using the above commands, then Eclipse Android runs are very stable.

Answer (score 0):

> 'am start -n com.example.abstab/com.example.abstab.ActivityMain -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on
>   device HT15CV805781

**HT15CV805781** might  have a problem with device

> at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:453)

that line of exception indicate that your application having trouble to executing in device .

Reboot device may help sometimes , or restart the connection of adb bridge .

Comment: thanks for your response.I restarted my device(AVD) and also restarted adb bridge with **adb kill-server and adb start-server**. But it didnt work.It gives same error. Device configuration is attached as here: [Device configuration](http://postimg.org/image/5wih4nxd1/)

Comment: I have updated question. can you look at in seesion data : BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US .Is there any problem here of win 32/64 bit.I am using win 64 bit version.

Comment: make sure you have download SDK for 64 bit .

Comment: Yes,I have downloaded SDK for 64 bit.I have edited question but it is not visible to you untill Ruben(owner of question) review it.So i edited my question [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131524/emulator-screen-hangs-when-trying-to-run-android-application) Please dont mark it as duplicate because i ask it before bounty.

Comment: @FastTrack I will not accept your edits to this post, as you are experiencing this problem with the emulator and I had it with a physical device. However, I do believe a solution for either one of us can solve both or problems. If you have your problem solved, I shall mark this one as solved as well...

Answer (score 0):

try this command:

```
adb.exe kill-server
adb.exe start-server
adb.exe shell am start -n com.example.abstab/.ActivityMain
```