# JAVA is required to run android project in eclipse for windows 7

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, startup

I am newbie to android so i wonder java installation is required to run android project from eclipse SDK ?

If it is required then i already installed it. Then why i am getting this error:[Error while running android project in eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131524/emulator-screen-hangs-when-trying-to-run-android-application)

Comment: There is no must to use eclipse IDE. You can use [Android studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) introduced by [Google](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmv1dTnhLH4).

Comment: @Ali So,In android studio, Java is not required?

Comment: Right now, Android Studio is an early-release preview (0.1.5). Unless you are already an Android expert, I do not recommend using Android Studio until it is released in a 1.0 (or equivalent) version. And Java is definitely required for Android Studio use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For starters, you cannot run Eclipse without Java, as Eclipse is a Java application. You also cannot compile an Android application without a compatible JDK installed.

Please read [the "Get the Android SDK" page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), especially the "System Requirements" section.

Comment: thanks for your response.Yes i have java installed but i an getting error as i already posted here..Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131524/emulator-screen-hangs-when-trying-to-run-android-application . I have java installed but i have different version of JDK and JRE. Is this problem related to this or any other reason? Thank you.

Comment: @FastTrack: Java has nothing to do with the emulator, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: The emulator itself doesn't require java, but many such as the poster are launching it under control of a host-side Java program.  It's not clear if the problem is with the emulator itself or with this interface to it.  Interacting with the emulator via adb from the command line would be a common next step for someone experienced with android, but interpreting things like logcat, and ps or top to figure out what the emulator is doing can take some experience.  Another idea is to test the emulator by starting it without an application project, and running something from its launcher.