# can android use third party emulator or simulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there any option to use third party emulator or simulator because i am using eclips inbuilt emulator and speed of that is very slow.

so i want to use third party emulator which perform better than eclips emulator.

thanks in advance .

Comment: Try on real device if possible..

Comment: yes i am using but if for some programs more than one devices. so i am using emulator  and it is working very slow...

Comment: There are many who are crying because of the slow emulator, try [Android x86 explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17319580/2345913).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Real device always give you best performance and speed, after all emulator is virtual device you can't expect all the features and functionality as in real device.

One more thing, if you start emulator then it will use RAM of the machine and configuration too. So you must be having good configuration if you want to develop app and testing on emulator.

Any way, you can try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) which is promising one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes you are right but on other hand iPhone simulator is working perfectly or  with high speed . thats why i am thinking there must be the solution to increase the speed of emulator

Comment: @AmitSharma you can't make comparison with iPhone simulator because they have their own configuration where as here Android can be developed on heterogeneous platforms. And it loads Android OS especially so means that you have 2 OS running on your machine.

Comment: no actually i am working with the iPhone dev. Team so. i have single OS on my machine.

Comment: @AmitSharma dear iOS development is done on their own os i.e. MacOS so they know what their development configuration should be.

Comment: ok i am little bit confused. actualy i am fresher in android so i was thinking that type of questions :) thanks every one

Answer (score 1):

Paresh Mayani is wright, for now there is no better solution than a real device. But There are two more emulators:

[Oracles Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
[Virtualbox tutorial](http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich-in-virtualbox/2012/03/02)

and

[Bluestack´s emulator](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

Both emulators are a little bit faster than the AVD Manager, but even slow. The Bluestacks Emulator is made for playing on PC, until now I can´t find a way to set multiple screen sizes to make a real comparison to devices. 
But with Blue Stacks You can also get Apps from Playstore and after installing, the emulator is automatically shown in Eclipse when You run Your project.

Answer (score 0):

you can use virtual box to be fast. this is best way for you.

for help and guide line you can use below link. hope you will success.

http://standroid.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-4-x86-in-virtualbox.html