# how to make Android emulator to run fast

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am using eclipe IDE for Android app development.But the problem is that Eclipes emulator is runng very slowly.Currently I am on `core i3` system and allotating emulator to a `RAM of 1 GB` but still my output comes after delay of 10 minutes.I am new to android. plz help

Comment: what's your system ram?

Comment: You may want to try running on hardware instead. http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: Try to Use Ubuntu OS.

Comment: I am on a processor of 2.93 GB and RAM 2 GB

Comment: Check my answer here: [**can android use third party emulator or simulator?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359357/can-android-use-third-party-emulator-or-simulator/17359405#17359405)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use an x86 emulator. 
First install IntelHaxm.exe, you have it on Android_SDK_Root\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

(if you don't have this file, install Intel Atom x86 System Image by Intel Corporation as you can see on the tutorial)

and follow this tutorial:
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/configuring_the_x86_emulator

Answer (score 2):

It probably won't. The emulator is useless.

However try [this](http://www.genymotion.com) they have an android emulator, and it runs incredibly fast. Faster than some actual devices.

Comment: The emulator is really useless. I don't understand why they can't decide this problem till now

Answer (score 0):

The only decent thread that I ever found is [this one](http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/development/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator/). There's a lot of information there and I hope it will be useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

If your emulator is taking a while to start, you should enable snapshot. Go to your AVD Manager (Window->AVD Manager), edit the emulator, and enable snapshot. 
This will speed up booting your emulator.

Comment: The issue is not the starting of emulator but the issue is that out put takes a long while to display

Comment: Ah ok, dont know that issue.. Good luck with that

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to clear the emulator you're working on, delete it and start a new copy. As you working, loading and reloading it tends to get clogged up...

Answer (score 0):

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-4-2-jelly-bean-installation-instructions-recommended

Follow these link by installing intel x86 emulator it is very fast which u cant imagine the speed . It is working fine for me if u have any query post me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Genymotion. I think that It's a very simple and effective way.http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/genymotion-fast-easy-to-use-android-x86.html